# google polymer and firebase document change data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I'm building a web app with polymer and I'm using firebase as a database. I want to build a user email conformation website. -> When the website opens a simple firebase node should be updated. My email-confirmahtml:

```
<dom-module id="email-confirmation">
    <template>
      <firebase-document
        id="idd"
        location="[[location]]"
        data="{{userToConfirm}}"
        on-data-changed="callMe">
      </firebase-document>

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{isConfirmed(userToConfirm)}}">
        <p>It worked!</p>
      </template>
    </template>
  <script src="./email-confirmation.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

and my email-confirmation.js:

```
class EmailConfirmation {
  beforeRegister() {
    this.is = 'email-confirmation';
    this.properties = {
      /**
       * Defines the email, that will be confirmed.
       */
      email: {
        type: String
      }
    };
    this.observers = [
      // Note that this function  will not fire until *all* parameters
      // given have been set to something other than `undefined`
      'attributesReady(email)'
    ];
  }

  attributesReady(email) {
    this.location = document.createElement('iron-meta').byKey('firebaseLocation') + 'users/' + email;
  }

  isConfirmed(bla) {
    this.userToConfirm.confirmed = true;
    bla.confirmed = true;
    return true;
  }

  callMe(event, values) {
    this.userToConfirm.confirmed = true;
    event.detail.value.confirmed = true;
    event.currentTarget.data.confirmed = true;
    this.$.idd.data = true;
    values.value.confirmed = true;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to use different methods here. But none of this calls actually updates my firebase node! How should can I update my node with javascript?

I also think there might be a problem with notifying firebase-document, that the values have changed. I tried to fire an event, but they do not seem to reach firebase-document. (Probably because the events are not fired to the childs)

Kind regards
Marc

Comment: I'd love to help. But there are too many missing pieces here for me to fill in. Can you create a minimal, complete verifiable example: something that reproduces just the question you are asking. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the quick reply! I updated my question, for more information. Please take a second look, really appreciating it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `query` property

`this.$.idd.query.set('confirmed', true);`

Comment: Hi Alexander!
Thank you very much, this worked like a charm :)